# synchronization between processes using unnamed semaphores

Tags: c, posix, ipc, shared-memory, semaphore

In `process-1` I am trying to write the data into shared memory. At the same time in `process-2` I am reading the data from the same shared memory. in this case I need to provide synchronization between these two processes. if I will go through unnamed semaphores (using `shm_init(),mmap()`),will it work or not?

I have written code like this will it work or not?

```
fd = shm_open("shm_name", O_CREAT| O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

sema = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED , fd, 0);

sem_init(sema, 1, 1);
```

Comment: sem_init afaik is for threads .

Answer (score 6):

The general approach will work. Note the following however:

- The `name` argument to `shm_open(3)` should start with a slash. Pass `"/shm_name"` instead. (On Linux with glibc, it happens to work without the slash, IIRC.)
- You need to resize `fd` with an `ftruncate(2)`, or you'll get a `SIGBUS` when you try to access the shared memory. Whenever you `mmap(2)` a file, any memory you access in the mapping must actually exist in the file, and POSIX shared memory objects work the same way. (On Linux, they're implemented as files under `/dev/shm`, which uses an in-memory [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt).)
- If you plan to use the semaphore to synchronize operations on a shared memory mapping, then it's redundant to create a separate shared memory mapping just for the semaphore. Make it a part of the mapping you're synchronizing operations on instead.

For the latter, you could do e.g. the following:

```
typedef struct Shared_mem {
    sem_t sem;
    int shared_data[100];
} Shared_mem;

...

shared_mem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(Shared_mem), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                  MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

...

sem_init(&shared_mem->sem, 1, 1);
```

Comment: A big +1 to this response.

I got involved with a piece of code that did the same thing:  use mmap for interprocess sharing, but use a bucketload of shm_* calls to create the named semaphores, which required all kinds of reverse-engineering, filename building (/dev/shm/sem.*) for multiple files (yes, semaphores plural), string munging, etc.  I had the same idea and "moved" the named semaphores as unnamed semphores into the file that was already being shared, and all that ugliness went away!

Comment: The only hiccup I had was that the original code would call sem_init on the named semaphores, which is not necessary, whether it was the process creating a new semaphore or opening an existing semaphore.

Apparently that did not matter for named semaphores, because the ugly code worked.  However, when I converted it to unnamed semaphores in mmap'ed file memory, it mattered big time.  

My point is that when the man page for sem_init says "Initializing a semaphore that has already been initialized results in undefined behavior," pay attention!