# Making an array of ints visible to child processes using mmap

Tags: c, global-variables, shared-memory, dining-philosopher

I am working on the dining philosopher's problem and can't use threads so I need to use shared memory to make the array of chopsticks and philosophers visible to all child processes. I am trying to use mmap, however, my use of mmap is incorrect and I am unsure how to fix it since my argument is an array of ints not an int as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254270/c-unix-mmap-array-of-int). Should I be using a different function to make it in shared memory?

```
(declared at the global scope)
int chopsticks[5];
int sizeOfSticks=sizeof(int)*5;
void* map = mmap(0,sizeOfSticks,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,chopsticks,0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second-to-last argument to `mmap()` is a file descriptor, for cases where you're mapping a file into memory. If you just need to allocate some shared memory, then do this instead:

```
int *chopsticks;

...

chopsticks = mmap(NULL, N_CHOPSTICKS*sizeof(int),
                  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED,
                  -1, 0);
```

`MAP_ANONYMOUS` means the mapping has no corresponding file. Passing 0 for `fd` is likely to work too, but -1 might be more portable (see e.g. the `mmap(2)` man page on Linux).

The mapping will be inherited by `fork(2)`'d child processes.

As a small style side note, you could write `N_CHOPSTICKS*sizeof(*chopsticks)` instead of `N_CHOPSTICKS*sizeof(int)`. That way the size will still be correct even if you change the type of `chopsticks`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I implemented this and it is throwing an error saying that "initializer element is not consistent"

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Did you write `int *chopsticks = mmap(...)` and not `int chopsticks[5] = mmap(...)`? `chopsticks` will have to be a pointer.

Comment: yes, my line is `int* chopsticks=mmap(NULL, STICKS*sizeof(int),PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);`
where STICKS is defined as 5 at the global

Comment: @CodeMonkey: On what line are you getting that error? Did you remove the original `int chopsticks[5]` too?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: If you want to, you could paste your current code to pastie.org. Less guessing that way.

Comment: The line itself is fine, so it has to be another issue in your code.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Ahhh... just noticed you're declaring things at global scope. What you need to do instead is to have a separate `int *chopsticks;` declaration globally, and do `chopsticks = mmap(...)` inside your function. Sorry for missing that! You can't call functions in initializers for global objects. *(Edited the answer now too.)*

Comment: (That's assuming you really need to have it globally. Otherwise, you could make it local too. :)

Comment: I implemented these changes but now I am getting the error "data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]" I declared `int*chopsticks` at the global and declared inside my main (as the first line)
`    chopsticks=mmap(NULL, STICKS*sizeof(int),PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);`

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Probably easiest if you paste your code on pastie.org and link it here in the comments so I can see it.

Comment: You didn't forget the semicolon at the end of `int *chopsticks`, right?

Comment: There are other errors as well, but I am just trying to get the mapping to work. Would it be easier to do shmget and the functions regarding that

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Note that the error is on the `int semId = semget(...)` line. You can't call `semget(2)` when initializing a global variable. (That's why the error message complains that the initializer is not constant.) I recommend that you use POSIX semaphores by the way (e.g., `sem_init(3)`), as they're much simpler (you're currently using System V semaphores), but you would need to read up on how to use them though.

Comment: Sorry for the self-plug, but there's an example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29226417/4577158 by the way. (Write the `mmap()` like in the answer here instead -- the example in the linked answer uses a mechanism you probably don't need). This is pretty heavy stuff if you're really new to C though. The `mmap()` in my answer is correct at least.